# How to check for a value before '.' in BASH

Tags: json, bash

I'm outputting some values to JSON format, and it appears if a value starts with a '.' it isn't valid JSON (The API doesn't seem to like these int's inside " "). What would be the best way to check if my value has anything in front of a '.', and if not, put a 0 there?

i.e

```
value = .53
newvalue = 0.53
```

I'm not very good at doing anything more than simple functions in BASH at the moment, still trying to learn awk/sed and other useful things such as cut.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using Bash? Seems an odd language to be generating JSON in...

Comment: `printf "%f" $oldvalue` would work, might result in some other slight side effects other then leading `0`'s due to the nature of floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a number of possible solutions given the nature of the input.  However, given those unknowns an easy workaround would be to say:

```
[[ $value == \.* ]] && newvalue=0${value}
```

Example:

```
$ value=.42
$ [[ $value == \.* ]] && newvalue=0${value}
$ echo $newvalue
0.42
```